# Formating SQL XML-field in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a SQL table with some normal fields and one xml-type field.
I need help with formatting the xml-type field. I want to display the the information in a gridview in asp.net but i want to apply formatting to it.

Does anyone know how I need to do?

Thanks.

PS. If it's to any help, I use a linqdatasource as source to my gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to accomplish my goal with the help of the xml webcontrol and a xslt document

```
<asp:xml document='<%# Eval("Attributes") %>' transformationsource="myxsltdocument.xslt" runat="server" />
```